# Some books about Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I just have finished Topology of Munkres and want to learn more Algebraic Topology . What's book which I can read now ? I know some books with authors like : " Allan Hatcher [ but I think I can't be suitable with his style ] , Rotman , Massey , ... " . Anybody help me ?

Comment: [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-best-books-for-algebraic-topology.html) is a good short references list. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: If you want something different, looking to the future,  try http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html .

Answer (score 0):

I will also never get comfortable with Hatcher's style. Perhaps, you, like me, will like "Algebraic Topology" by Tammo tom Dieck. I think it's pretty much my favorite. Spanier is also great. Note... there are a lot of questions like this on SO, already.

Comment: Now I'm reading " A basic course in algebraic topology " - W.Massey . :) I like his style . Should we contact in another website ? Because we seem to be learning the same section at that time .

Comment: Sure, aren't there are chats and chatrooms here on SO? However, I have an exam on Friday, and since I've been too slow, I'm likely to fail/ have a bad grade. So I'm not even sure I'll be doing much more AT in the future T.T Either way, I have to say I always appreciate meeting others with the same preference on how to learn certain things in Mathematics :)

Comment: Me too , I think we can contact each others by facebook or ... . I'm learning mathematics by myself with no teacher or pro ..( It's simply because I love mathematics ) . I read book at free time and do quite little exercises so I'm just interested in theoritical problems . But I think we can have good discussions

Comment: Sounds good! I'm 'Alex Yi' on Facebook. The cover photo is some graffiti, my photo is... well I have a beard, black short hair, white background. And I'm making a face [like this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RmwN2xBAbuY/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: Give me the link to your wall

Comment: I feel a little uncomfortable posting links to my Facebook pages publicly... can you not find me with the given information? More info: I look (Half-)Asian